# Is using Passport authentication for my ASP.NET site secure? What are the other pros and cons?

Tags: asp.net-authentication

I have been having a look at secure and 'correct' ways of handling authentication within my ASP.NET site and have found the Passport Authentication Provider.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8e50t0f%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

I've done some research but I'm still skeptical about this being a good idea, does anyone have any other opinion? Have you tried this out before?

Comment: I wouldn't be looking to use this in new development. It kind of made sense back in ~2003, not so much now.

Comment: Passport is an old technology. You might want to use the newer [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity) infrastructure for authentication, authorization etc.

Comment: @vape Thanks for your reply. If you want to post an answer I will accept it to give you the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passport is an old technology. You might want to use the newer [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity) infrastructure for authentication, authorization etc.